# How to check if data structure is a collection or a list in TCL

Tags: tcl

How do i perform a check like this?

```
if {} {
// code if it is collection
} else {
//code for list
}
```

Do you creatively use sizeof / llength and prevent that from failing? or there's a native command that does this cleanly?

Comment: TCL does not have data structures or collections or even lists natively.  Everything in TCL is a string, so you would need some command to tell if a string was a "collection" or a "list" by parsing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collection is not standard to Tcl, but is a type of object available in Synopsys design tools.

If you are referring to Synopsys collections, all collection have a string representation like `_sel123` or `_sel456`.  You can check this:

```
if {[regexp {^_sel\d+$} $obj]} {
    # $obj is most likely a collection
} else {
    # $obj is something else
}
```

Comment: thanks! this sounds great, will test this and share back!! thanks

Comment: Thanks! tested this out, and with the minor tool related tweak what you shared works well :)

regexp {^0x[0-9a-zA-Z]+$} $incoming_variable ; # collections in this tool were of the form 0x followed by digits and letters